# Querying DataTable

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I have a datatable which contains yearly data saved. e.g.

```
dtDate                      Value
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000     5.0000
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000     15.0000
2012-01-01 00:00:00.000     25.0000
2013-01-01 00:00:00.000     35.0000
2014-01-01 00:00:00.000     45.0000
```

Now i want to use this datatable for monthly process. so for all months in year 2010 i want to use value=5. e.g. If my date is 02/01/2010 Feb 2010 it should return me

How do I use `datatable.select` method? I want some effective filter expression.

Comment: If you can provide a working solution for this query, will surely accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataTable.Select(filterExpression) overload method contains the parameter filterExpression that use the same syntax used to create calculated columns via the [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) property.

You could use this code to get required row

```
Dim dt as DateTime dt = new DateTime(2010,1,1,0,0,0)
Dim r as DataRow() r = DataTable.Select("dtDate = #" + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "#");
```

If your intention is to get the record for year 2010 passing any date with year = 2010 then you could use this syntax

```
' Supposing date passed is 1/May/2010 and you want the record with 2010 as year.
Dim dt as DateTime dt = new DateTime(2010,5,1,0,0,0)  
Dim r as DataRow() r = DataTable.Select("dtDate = #01/01/" + dt.Year.ToString()) + "#");
```

Comment: DataTable.Select("dtDate = #" + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "#");                                                              This will not return any row because there isn't any row with dtDate '01/02/2010'

Comment: Oh well, it was just an example, however changed the date. Rereading your question, now I have a doubt. IF you have as date 2010-Feb-01 you wish to get the record  (only one) for year 2010? and so on?

Comment: Then the second example above should works. I suppose that the data for a full year is stored in a record with `dtDate` equals to the first of January of the requested year.